# Email not being generated or script not firing?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, email

I have this working to generate an email but if the "ComplaintTextbox" contains more than like 30 characters an email does not generate.??

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   function sendMail(CustomerTextbox, AddressTextBox, CityTextBox, StateDropDown, ZipTextBox, ModelTextbox, SerialTextbox, ReferenceTextbox, ComplaintTextBox, WarrentyTextBox) {
   var CustomerTextbox = document.getElementById(CustomerTextbox).value;
   var AddressTextBox = document.getElementById(AddressTextBox).value;
   var CityTextBox = document.getElementById(CityTextBox).value;
   var StateDropDown = document.getElementById(StateDropDown).value;
   var ZipTextBox = document.getElementById(ZipTextBox).value;
   var ModelTextbox = document.getElementById(ModelTextbox).value;
   var SerialTextbox = document.getElementById(SerialTextbox).value;
   var ReferenceTextbox = document.getElementById(ReferenceTextbox).value;
   var ComplaintTextBox = document.getElementById(ComplaintTextBox).value;
   var WarrentyTextBox = document.getElementById(WarrentyTextBox).value;

   var body = "Please issue a RMA for this case." + "\r\n";
   body += CustomerTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += AddressTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += CityTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += StateDropDown + "\r\n";
   body += ZipTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += ModelTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += SerialTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += ReferenceTextbox + "\r\n";
   body += ComplaintTextBox + "\r\n";
   body += WarrentyTextBox + "\r\n";
```

Comment: Why don't you include more code such as the asp:TextBox with the id CustomerTextbox and a snippet of code with a working button

Comment: Did you verify with IE F12 tools that nothing is being reported to the console?

Comment: I thought that is what I have in the second code line? "cmdEmail1"

Comment: Yes, I tried the F12 nothing

Comment: Ok I got it working but It is only shows a blank page when "City" is included in the string var body = "Please issue a RMA for this case." + "\r\n" + "Customer Name: " + CustomerTextbox + "\r\n" + "Customer Address: " + AddressTextBox + "\r\n" + "City" 

When I change "City" to "" it works???

Answer (score 0):

You should not be causing a full postback with this. You are trying to call a javascript function with an ASP.NET Submit button, simply changing this

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="sendMail('<%=CustomerTextbox.ClientID %>')">
            <asp:Button ID="cmdEmail1" runat="server" Text="Generate Email RMA" 
                Width="158px" />
            </a>
```

to this:

```
  <a href="#" onclick="sendMail('<%=CustomerTextbox.ClientID %>')">
            Generate Email RMA
            </a>
```

will start to make your web development life much easier and more scalable.

Comment: When I try this I get Server Error in '/' Application.
The resource cannot be found. Requested URL: /0

Comment: I am just trying to steer you in the right direction, it would be helpful if you would post a working example of your code so I can see the end goal clearly. What is important about my answer is that it is showing you that you can all your javascript without a submit button doing a postback to the server. What you do within your javascript is still broken.

Comment: Ok I got it working but It is only shows a blank page when "City" is included in the string  var body = "Please issue a RMA for this case." + "\r\n" + "Customer Name: " + CustomerTextbox + "\r\n" + "Customer Address: " + AddressTextBox + "\r\n" + "City"

Comment: When I change "City" to "" it works???

Comment: Are you trying to just prompt a user that they need to issue a RMA for this case?

Comment: Looks like the Complaint textbox is the culperite if there is more that a certain amount of characters the email does not generate?